# Removing event listener in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dojo, dom-events

In Firefox and Chrome my code works fine but in IE the event does not get removed.

```
dojo.connect(d, "onmouseout", function(evt) {
    //remove event
});
```

I've tried:

```
document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyHandler);
dojo.disonnect(document, "keydown", keyHandler);
document.detachEvent("keydown", keyHandler);
```

But nothing seems to work. `keyHandler` is the function which I don't want to execute on `keydown` when the mouse is out of the canvas stored in variable `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working with this command: `document.onkeydown = null;`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the `disconnect` function properly (and check the spelling/syntax as well). The [documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/disconnect.html) says:

> disconnect() accepts a specially-crafted parameter as it’s only
>   argument which, coincidentally, is the return value from dojo.connect.

...while you supply 3 parameters to it, the handler being the last one.

As a side note, I am not quite sure about what happens inside Dojo (though it probably implements a polyfill, so you don't have to use native functions if you use Dojo), but IE's `attachEvent` and `detachEvent` accepts event names prefixed with 'on', e.g. `onmouseout`, `onkeydown` (see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ie/ms536411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Also, note the difference in event names. Dojo seems to use IE's syntax with `on` prefix, while the standard DOM implementation [omits it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener). So, you may want to check if you are binding and unbinding the same event (e.g. if you bind to `onkeydown`, then you should unbind `onkeydown` and not `keydown`).